# How to write a test for Elasticsearch custom plugin?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I create custom **Elasticsearch** plugin. Now I want to write a test for this plugin.
My expectations were - that I could run embedded **Elasticsearch** instance, set up it properly and then do some testing (index some documents, then query for it)

Problem is that I couldn't set up my plugin properly

Custom plugin code is parsing JSON query and set up some objects for later usage:

```
public class CustomQueryParserPlugin extends AbstractPlugin {
    public static final String PLUGIN_NAME = "custom_query";
    private final Settings settings;

    @Inject
    public CustomQueryParserPlugin (Settings settings) {
        this.settings = settings;
    }

    @Override
    public String name() {
        return PLUGIN_NAME;
    }

    @Override
    public String description() {
        return "custom plugin";
    }

    public void onModule(IndicesQueriesModule module) {
        module.addQuery(new CustomQueryParser(settings));
    }
}
```

Test code:

```
public class CustomParserPluginTest extends ElasticsearchSingleNodeTest {

    private static Node newNode() {
        final Settings settings = ImmutableSettings.builder()
                .put(ClusterName.SETTING, nodeName())
                .put("node.name", nodeName())
                .put(IndexMetaData.SETTING_NUMBER_OF_SHARDS, 1)
                .put(IndexMetaData.SETTING_NUMBER_OF_REPLICAS, 0)
                .put(EsExecutors.PROCESSORS, 1) // limit the number of threads created
                .put("http.enabled", false)
                .put("plugin.types", CustomParserPlugin.class.getName())
                .put("path.plugins", pathToPlugin)
                .put("index.store.type", "ram")
                .put("config.ignore_system_properties", true) // make sure we get what we set :)
                .put("gateway.type", "none").build();
        Node build = NodeBuilder.nodeBuilder().local(true).data(true).settings(
                settings).build();
        build.start();
        assertThat(DiscoveryNode.localNode(build.settings()), is(true));
        return build;
    }


    @Test
    public void jsonParsing() throws URISyntaxException {
        final Client client = newNode().client();
        final SearchResponse test = client.prepareSearch("test-index").setSource(addQuery()).execute().actionGet();
    }

    private String addQuery() {
         return "{"match_all":{"boost":1.2}}"
    }
```

I've try multiple values for **pathToPlugin** - but nothing seems to works well, because JSON query always give me an exception:

```
QueryParsingException[[test-index] No query registered for [custom_query]];
```

All documentation I could find was about installing plugins and testing them on some local Elasticsearch installation.

What I am doing wrong here? Is there any documentation or examples of tests like that?

**UPD**. Here is a repo with extracted code of CustomQueryParserPlugin - https://github.com/MysterionRise/es-custom-parser

May be in initialize section in test I need to create in memory index?

Comment: May you share whole file with the `CustomQueryParserPlugin` class and a directory tree for this plugin?

Comment: @Rob, thanks for your attention, I've create a repo with all extracted code for this example. I will update question immediately

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To write tests for you plugin you can use [Elasticsearch Cluster Runner](https://github.com/codelibs/elasticsearch-cluster-runner). 
For reference check how [MinHash Plugin](https://github.com/codelibs/elasticsearch-minhash) wrote test.

**UPDATE:**

I've changed `CustomParserPluginTest` class to use Elasticsearch Cluster Runner:

```
import static org.codelibs.elasticsearch.runner.ElasticsearchClusterRunner.newConfigs;
import java.util.Map;
import junit.framework.TestCase;
import org.codelibs.elasticsearch.runner.ElasticsearchClusterRunner;
import org.elasticsearch.action.get.GetResponse;
import org.elasticsearch.action.index.IndexResponse;
import org.elasticsearch.client.Client;
import org.elasticsearch.common.bytes.BytesArray;
import org.elasticsearch.common.settings.ImmutableSettings;
import org.elasticsearch.common.settings.ImmutableSettings.Builder;
import org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.XContentBuilder;
import org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.XContentFactory;
import org.elasticsearch.index.get.GetField;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchResponse;
import static org.hamcrest.core.Is.is;

public class CustomParserPluginTest extends TestCase {

    private ElasticsearchClusterRunner runner;

    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        // create runner instance
        runner = new ElasticsearchClusterRunner();
        // create ES nodes
        runner.onBuild(new ElasticsearchClusterRunner.Builder() {
            @Override
            public void build(final int number, final Builder settingsBuilder) {
            }
        }).build(newConfigs().ramIndexStore().numOfNode(1));

        // wait for yellow status
        runner.ensureYellow();
    }

    @Override
    protected void tearDown() throws Exception {
        // close runner
        runner.close();
        // delete all files
        runner.clean();
    }

    public void test_jsonParsing() throws Exception {
        final String index = "test_index";

        runner.createIndex(index, ImmutableSettings.builder().build());
        runner.ensureYellow(index);

        final SearchResponse test = runner.client().prepareSearch(index).setSource(addQuery()).execute().actionGet();
    }

    private String addQuery() {
        return "{\"match_all\":{\"boost\":1.2}}";
    }
}
```

I've created `es-plugin.properties`(pluginrootdirectory\src\main\resources) file with following content which will force elasticsearch instance to load plugin:

```
plugin=CustomQueryParserPlugin
```

When you will run the this test you will see in the output that the newly created insance of elasticsearch loaded the plugin.

> [2015-04-29 19:22:10,783][INFO ][org.elasticsearch.node   ] [Node 1]
>   version[1.5 .0], pid[34360], build[5448160/2015-03-23T14:30:58Z]
>   [2015-04-29 19:22:10,784][INFO ][org.elasticsearch.node   ] [Node 1]
>   initializin g ... [2015-04-29 19:22:10,795][INFO
>   ][org.elasticsearch.plugins] [Node 1] loaded [**custom_query**], sites []
>   [2015-04-29 19:22:13,342][INFO ][org.elasticsearch.node   ] [Node 1]
>   initialized
>
> [2015-04-29 19:22:13,342][INFO ][org.elasticsearch.node   ] [Node 1]
>   starting .. .

Hope this helps.

Comment: Note that as of version 2.1 Elasticsearch does not load plugins from classpath anymore. See the discussion here: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/add-plugins-from-classpath-in-embedded-elasticsearch-client-node/36269/6

To have it still load your plugin you'd need to provide a `plugin.types` setting with the FQN of the plugin (comma-separated in case there are multiple)